# How can I get the following collection to return the original type?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following method which I cast to `ICloseable` to expose the property I want to check against.

Problem is that the return type is now a Set of type `ICloseable`.

Is there a way of checking whether `T` is closed without it returning a Set of type `ICloseable`?

```
if (typeof(ICloseable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    return base.Set<T>().Where(n => !((ICloseable)n).Closed);
}
```

Comment: It really shouldn't be. It should still be an `IEnumerable<T>`. What makes you think it's a `Set<ICloseable>`? And what is the type of `Set<T>()` to start with?

Comment: 'Unable to cast the type 'SomeType' to type 'ICloseable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.' This is the exception am getting. Would suggest it has been cast to ICloseable?

Comment: Okay, that doesn't sound like the problem you talked about at all. How is that error in any way related to "the return type is now a Set of type ICloseable"? You should also tag your question to indicate that it's EF.

Comment: My apologies. I will tag it to EF also thanks for the tip.

Comment: That exception specifically says that it *can't* cast to `ICloseable`, which is kind of the opposite of the problem you're describing...

Comment: Yes I forgot about the deferred execution and was looking at the exception a bit further up the stack :S Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `IQueryable<T>` is covariant in T, you could try:

```
if (typeof(ICloseable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    IQueryable<ICloseable> closeables = (IQueryable<ICloseable>) base.Set<T>();
    return closeables.Where(n => !n.Closed).Cast<T>();
}
```

I don't know whether the `Cast` will definitely work, but it's worth a try.